# Integer properties of object not populating defaultValues in HTML input fields of a form in a modal

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, bootstrap-modal

I have a table of objects that each have several properties with/without data. Each object has a dedicated 'Edit' button assigned to themselves so that, when clicked on, the application opens a modal with a form for that specific object. Naturally, I want this edit form of text and number input fields to show the values of the object that it may/may not already have. For that reason I'm using HTMLs `defaultValue` property of their input-tag.

My problem is that, the way I've done it works for all string values, but not for number values. It would have made sense to me if both strings and numbers wouldn't show, but the fact that ONLY the number values won't show really confuses me. Here are the important snippets of my code (ignore any missing div-tags etc.):

**Using TypeScript and React:**

```js
const [ship, setShip] = useState({
        shipId: 0,
        cruiselineId: 0,
        name: "",
        shipCode: "",
        classId: 0,
        guestNumber: 0,
        staffNumber: 0,
        creationYear: 0,
        weight: 0,
        length: 0,
        passagerDeck: 0,
        handicapCabins: 0,
        nationality: "",
        className: ""
    });

const getShip = (
    id: number,
    GET_SHIPS_URL: string,
    setShip: (value: React.SetStateAction<{
        shipId: number;
        cruiselineId: number;
        name: string;
        shipCode: string;
        classId: number;
        guestNumber: number;
        staffNumber: number;
        creationYear: number;
        weight: number;
        length: number;
        passagerDeck: number;
        handicapCabins: number;
        nationality: string;
        className: string;
    }>) => void
) => {
    if (id != 0) {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(GET_SHIPS_URL + '/' + id)
                const json = await response.json()
                setShip(json)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error', error)
            }
        }
      fetchData()
    }
}

function nullToEmpty(value: string | number | null) {
    if (value === null) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

function changeTable(
    s: ShipModel,
    checkedLanguageTable: {
        id: boolean;
        name: boolean;
        shortCode: boolean;
        class: boolean;
        guestNumber: boolean;
        staffNumber: boolean;
        creationYear: boolean;
        weight: boolean;
        length: boolean;
        passengerDeck: boolean;
        handicap: boolean;
        nationality: boolean;
    }
) {

    var builtString = '';

    if (checkedLanguageTable.id) {
        builtString = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.shipId) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.name) {
        builtString = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.name) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.shortCode) {
        builtString = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.shipCode) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.class) {
        builtString = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.className) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.guestNumber) {
        builtString = builtString  + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.guestNumber) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.staffNumber) {
        builtString = builtString  + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.staffNumber) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.creationYear) {
        builtString = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.creationYear) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.weight) {
        builtString  = builtString  + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.weight) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.length) {
        builtString = builtString  + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.length) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.passengerDeck) {
        builtString  = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.passagerDeck) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.handicap) {
        builtString  = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.handicapCabins) + '</td>'
    }
    if (checkedLanguageTable.nationality) {
        builtString  = builtString + '<td>' + nullToEmpty(s.nationality) + '</td>'
    }

    return (
        <>
            {parse(testString)}
        </>
    )
}
```

**HTML code with bootstrap:**

```html
<table className="table table-row-bordered table-row-gray-300 gy-7" id="shipTable">
    <tbody>
        {tableHeaderSorter().map((s) => {
            return (
                <tr key={s.shipId}>
                    {changeTable(s, checkedLanguageTable)}
                    <td>
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <button className="btn2 btn dropdown-toggle"
                                type="button"
                                id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                            >
                                {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'MENU.ACTIONS' })}
                            </button>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        className="dropdown-item "
                                        data-bs-toggle='modal'
                                        data-bs-target='#kt_modal_edit'
                                        onClick={() => getShip(s.shipId, setSId, GET_SHIPS_URL, setShip)}
                                    >
                                        {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'EDIT' })} <i className="fas fa-edit text-warning"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        })}
    </tbody>
</table>

{/* -------------- EDIT ------------- */ }
<div className='modal fade' id='kt_modal_edit'>
    <div className='modal-dialog'>
        <div className='modal-content'>
            <div className='modal-header'>
                <h2 className='modal-title'>
                    {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'EDIT_DETAILS_SHIP' })} {ship.name}
                </h2>
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <form id='editingForm'>
                <div className="modal-body">

                    <div className='fv-row mb-10'>
                        <label className='d-flex align-items-center fs-5 fw-bold mb-2'>
                            <span>{intl.formatMessage({ id: "CLASS" })}</span>
                            <i
                                className='fas fa-exclamation-circle ms-2 fs-7'
                                data-bs-toggle='tooltip'
                                title={intl.formatMessage({ id: "CLASS_OF_NEW_SHIP" })}
                            ></i>
                        </label>

                        <div className="control">
                            <select
                                className="form-select select is-fullwidth mb-3"
                                name="classDropDown"
                                id="editClassDropDown"
                                onClick={() => dropDownTitleFunctionClassEdit(setClassId, setClassDropDownTitle)}
                            >
                                <option value={""}>{ship.className}</option>
                                {classOptions}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'SHIP_NAME' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editName' defaultValue={ship.name} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'SHIP_SHORT_CODE' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editShipCode' defaultValue={ship.shipCode} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'GUEST_NUMBER' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editGuestNumber' defaultValue={String(ship.guestNumber)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'STAFF_NUMBER' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editStaffNumber' defaultValue={String(ship.staffNumber)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'CREATION_YEAR' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editCreationYear' defaultValue={String(ship.creationYear)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'WEIGHT' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editWeight' defaultValue={String(ship.weight)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'LENGTH' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editLength' defaultValue={String(ship.length)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'PASSENGER_DECK' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editPassagerDeck' defaultValue={String(ship.passagerDeck)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'HADICAP_CABINS' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editHandicapCabins' defaultValue={String(ship.handicapCabins)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'NATIONALITY' })}</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id='editNationality' defaultValue={ship.nationality} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Things I've already tried that didn't work:**

1. Changing HTML input types from `"number"` to `"text"`
2. Removing `String()` cast of integer values in `defaultValue`
3. Using attempt #1 and #2 interchangeably

The only workaround I could find was to change the integer properties of my `ship` object to strings by replacing `0` with empty quotation marks `""` in the useState, and then later type cast them to integers before PUT'ing the object. But I refuse to believe that to be the proper solution to this problem.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the problem to a [mcve] (see the link for why that's useful even without asking a question), and if you still haven't solved it, please post a **runnable** MRE using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm assuming that comment was an automated message as it seems Stack Snippets are only compatible with JSX, not TSX, and are not using the same version of React as I am (which is 17.0.0). However, I've still edited my question and added declarations of some of the functions I'm using to hopefully paint a clearer picture. I'm still a pretty new dev, so if there are any specific questions regarding the code I've provided, then please do let me know.

Comment: You can still do a Stack Snippet, you just comment out any TypeScript type annotations or `type`/`interface` declarations. TypeScript is JavaScript plus type annotations (and a couple of minor other things, like creating automatic properties from constructor properties declared with `public` etc.).

Comment: Regardless, please see the edits I've made and point out anything that may be contextually confusing.